# How to add a class by click only one item from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays. On the first I add 'click'. And inside it there is another array. In the second array, when I click, I need to add the class only to the selected element of the array.

```
let mobileToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile__toggle').forEach(e => {

    e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        let evt = event.currentTarget           

        if (evt) {        
            document.querySelectorAll('.mobile__submenu').forEach(e => {
               e.classList.toggle('menu__open') 
            });              
        }               
    })
});
```

Thanks for the previous answer. This code works. But I have more nesting elements. In this case, the code does not work. Its part of my HTML code:

```
<li class="mobile__nav--item"><a href="#">Гитары</a><span class="mobile__toggle"></span></li>              
            <ul class="mobile__submenu">
              <li class="mobile__submenu--item"><a href="#">Акустические гитары</a></li>
                <li class="mobile__submenu--item-2"><a href="#">Вестерн гитары</a></li>
                <li class="mobile__submenu--item-2"><a href="#">Классические гитары</a></li>  
              <li class="mobile__submenu--item"><a href="#">Электроаккустические гитары</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.querySelectorAll` you could use `evt.querySelectorAll` which will select only those element which are under the current element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.mobile__toggle').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let evt = event.currentTarget
    if (evt) {
      evt.querySelectorAll('.mobile__submenu').forEach(e => {
        e.classList.toggle('menu__open')
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu__open {
  display: block !important;
}

.mobile__submenu {
  display: none;
}

.mobile__toggle:hover {
  width: 100px;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile__toggle">
  First
  <div class="mobile__submenu">11</div>
  <div class="mobile__submenu">12</div>
  <div class="mobile__submenu">13</div>
</div>
<div class="mobile__toggle">
  Second
  <div class="mobile__submenu">21</div>
  <div class="mobile__submenu">22</div>
  <div class="mobile__submenu">23</div>
</div>
```